# PGF-Pie - How to combine with \pgfplotstableread

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, pgf-pie

I was wondering how I can add a pgfplotstableread to this pie-chart. I have already defined one for you, but it is not linked to the table yet. 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\pgfplotstableread{
    Value, Name
    9, Blueberries
    7, Strawberries
    10, Pineapples
    16, Bananas
}\dataTable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie [rotate = 90,
text = legend,
sum=auto,
every only number node/.style={text=white},
color={blue,green,pink,yellow},] {
    9/Blueberries,
    7/Strawberries,
    10/Pineapples,
    16/Bananas}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of introducing `\pgfplotstableread`? So that you can use different separation symbols?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to have some quick `\expandafter` fun. Please don't use pie charts anyways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{%
Value, Name
9, \textbf{Blueberries}
7, Strawberries
10, $\displaystyle\int{\tan\theta d\theta}$
16, \emph{\textsf{Bananas}}
}\dataTable


\def\convertpgfplotstabletopie#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\mypie{}%
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}\edef\mytemprow{\pgfplotsretval}%
  \foreach\x in {0,...,\numexpr\mytemprow-1\relax}{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\x}{[index]#2}\of{#1}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\mytemp\expandafter{\pgfplotsretval}%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\x}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mytemp\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\mytemp\expandafter/\pgfplotsretval}%
    \ifnum\x<\numexpr\mytemprow-1\relax\expandafter\def\expandafter\mytemp\expandafter{\mytemp,}\fi%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mypie\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\mypie\mytemp}%
  }%
  \endgroup%
}
\def\pietable[#1]#2{%
\pgfkeys{#1}\expandafter\pie\expandafter{#2}%
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\convertpgfplotstabletopie{\dataTable}{0}{1}
\pietable[rotate = 90,text = legend,every only number node/.style={text=white},color={blue,green,pink,yellow}]{\mypie}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}
 \edef\pgfmarshal{
  \noexpand\pie[rotate=90,text=legend,every only number node/.style={text=white},color={blue,green,pink,yellow}]
  {\mypie}
 }
 \pgfmarshal
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Oh you said you want `\expandafter`-fun... so you have to put `\expandafter` between every single character starting from `[`, `r`, `o`, `t`, ... , until `l`, `w`, `o`, `]`.

Comment: @Symbol1 `\edef` will expand all the way. You can't use unexpandable stuff inside the text if you use that (which is why all this expand shananigan).

Comment: OK... how about `\def\pgfmarshal{\pie[...]}` and then `\expandafter\pgfmarshal\expandafter{\mypie}`.

Comment: @Symbol1 pgfmarshall is too close to `\pgf@marshall` :)

Comment: I suppose it is a temporary macro, so there should be no harm....... right???

Comment: @Symbol1 Yes it's the `\edef` macro for one of egreg's favorite tricks but missing the grouping : `\begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup....}\temp`. It's really neat